# Pasting from excel clipboard without interpreting dates

Tags: vba, excel, date, paste

I'm trying to paste the results from a SQL query into an excel spreadsheet using VBA, but it keeps interpreting dates incorrectly which means they cannot be processed later on.

My date looks like this (tsv)

```
Name    Total   Active  Start date  End date
xxxx    433 42  20/10/2017  09/01/2018
```

If you simply paste into the worksheet using Ctrl+V, then this is exactly what you get.

However, if I use, for example

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I get

```
Name    Vol Tot Start Date  End Date
xxxx    433 42  20/10/2017  01/09/2018
```

Note the switch of the end date from "09/01/2018" to "01/09/2018"

How do I stop VBA from trying to predict the format of the dates I am inputting? It is especially annoying as now the start date is in dd/mm/yyyy format while the end date is in mm/dd/yyyy which means I cannot process them together in the rest of the macro following this point. I would like to preserve both numbers in the original dd/mm/yyyy format (as they are in the input).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Format the target cells as "text" prior to pasting.

Comment: *Don't* copy the data. *Insert* the data (Data>Insert) and specify the appropriate locale, date settings. Excel can't guess that the format in the tsv is different than your own.

Comment: @vacip the source is a *text* file

Comment: I know, I'm talking about the target. Before you insert, do something like `Cells.NumberFormat = "@"`. Ugly but should do the trick.

Comment: Also, @PanagiotisKanavos is right, copy-paste is nasty, slow and error-prone. Use import, or even better, avoid VBA altogether and just link the data directly from the database

Comment: Maybe you should format the date at pastong, something like `format(yourdate,"dd/mm/yyyy")` or try to paste as Text or only values, without format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Vacip, the code

```
Columns("D:E").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Seems to work a treat.